# Generating a bitmap with freetype which size is a multiple of 4

Tags: c++, size, freetype

I want to create glyph bitmaps with FreeType, with sizes (both width and height) that are guaranteed to be a multiple of 4. Is there any way to do that with FreeType?

The reason I want it is because I'm generating Signed Distance Fields from monochrome bitmaps. The algorithm I use works better with larger source images, which I then will scale down by a factor 4.

I'm programming in C++11, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @SergeyK. There isn't very much for me to try. I have looked through the documentation, but I can't find any answer to my question there. Just using `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes()` doesn't work, because no matter what size I choose, the bitmaps don't turn out as I want.